# Is there more or less atmospheric pressure pressing down onto water having a larger atmosphere than of a smaller atmosphere?

Tags: pressure, atmospheric-science, buoyancy

[image: atmospheric pressure]

Is there more or less atmospheric pressure pressing down onto water having a larger atmosphere than of a smaller atmosphere?

Comment: Well, what do you think? And why?

Comment: Thanks for asking. It's a little confusing to me because with the same shapes of these two atmosphere If I had a vacuum I'd create less air pressure within making less pressure pressing onto the water. But say I didn't vacuum my guess is that the smaller atmosphere would have more pressure onto the water, but really I'm unsure if that's because the air would be more compressed in the smaller tank than of the larger tank or not. Here to learn! (:

Comment: You know now that I rethink of this I now think that the larger atmosphere would be more pressure pressing onto the water because of the added weight of the air! Assuming the smaller tank would only be greater in pressure only if the air was compressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there more or less atmospheric pressure pressing down onto water
>   having a larger atmosphere than of a smaller atmosphere?

If you mean by "larger atmosphere" you mean the height of the atmosphere, then yes there will be more atmospheric pressure down on the water if the height of the atmosphere is greater.

> You know now that I rethink of this I now think that the larger
>   atmosphere would be more pressure pressing onto the water because of
>   the added weight of the air! Assuming the smaller tank would only be
>   greater in pressure only if the air was compressed.

Yes there will be more pressure on the water with a greater (taller) atmosphere because of the added weight of the air. But just to get a sense of the increase  consider the fact that in our atmosphere the increase in pressure per meter above sea level is only about 11.3 pascals for the first 1000 meters height of atmosphere. Since the pressure of the atmosphere at sea level is approximately 100,000 Pascals, you can get a sense of the effect of atmospheric pressure on the increase in the water pressure in the tank.

Hope this helps.